# Are there Wolfram personnel here?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Wolfram Technical Support Officially Represented in this Forum?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377/is-wolfram-technical-support-officially-represented-in-this-forum)

Just wondering if somebody of the community members employed at Wolfram? Do they watch this site?